# Operator new throws an exception while a large amount of physical memory is available

Tags: c++, exception, memory

In my program I use operator new to allocate about 130 megabytes and an exception 
is thrown, but I find that there are more than 800 megabytes available in task manager.
I hope to know the relationship between physical memory indicated as available in
task manager and the memory that my program can use.

Another reason is the memory fragmentation. When I request memory allocation, the memory is
required as contiguous. Is there any way to know whether such contiguous memory exists or not?

Comment: The OS will make sure that contiguous memory is available (though it can take some time). It is very unlikely you're suffering from a lack of memory. Please show us how you allocate : post some code.

Comment: Windows, linux, osx? There are different (sometimes) configurable limits for each OS. As an administrator or regular user?

Comment: Thansk. The code that triggers the exception is very simple.          mesh->tris = new Triangle[mesh->numTris];  The value mesh->numTris is equal to about 5600000. The OS is Windows XP.

Comment: I believe that on a modern OS, the magic of virtual addressing ameliorates the fragmentation issue -- even if there is not literally 130 mb of *physically contiguous* memory, the OS can still provide 130 mb of contiguous *virtual addresses* to a userland process.

Comment: @goldilocks: What if the process's virtual address space is exhausted or sufficiently-fragmented?  (Not impossible in a 32-bit OS.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Then you are out of luck -- but 130 mb is not enough to do that somewhere with 32-bit addressess.

Comment: @goldilocks: It might exhaust if there is a memory leak in the code and the process is running for sufficiently long time. Then it will definitely fragment the virtual address space enough to cause the new to fail.

Comment: @goldilocks It cannot if application has already fragmented its virtual address space. OS cannot simply move existing pieces of application's data to new virtual addresses, despite being able to do something similar in the physical address space.

Comment: @goldilocks Contiguous physical memory is simply never an issue. What counts if contiguous virtual addresses.

Comment: I fully agree with Branko, David, Oli, ...  What goldilocks and Raveline are saying is plainly wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Physical memory <> Virtual memory.

If you are running a 32-bit application you can address at most 2 GB of memory (on a 32-bit OS).  Even your machine has 32 GB of physical memory, you are still limited to 2 GB.
If your machine has a minimal amount of physical memory (remember the days when we all had 128 MB of physical memory?), or you are running many other applications, then the size can be less than 2 GB (the whole page file has to be divided between all applications).

Even with 2 GB of memory, an allocation of 130MB could fail if there is no contiguous block of 130MB available.  Since Windows Vista, DLL's are spread randomly over the address space (look for: ASLR), which (in my experience) seems to cause lots of memory fragmentation.

There are several solutions to your problem:

- If you have control over the systems where you are running, you may disable ASLR for your system.  Don't do this if you are selling commercial software.  Your customers will not accept this.
- If your 32-bit app is running on 64-bit systems, give the application the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag (see linker flags or the editbin utility).  With this flag, your application should be able to address 4 GB instead of 2 GB.  Only do this if you are sure you are not doing 'dirty' things with pointers (e.g. subtracting to unrelated pointers).
- Allocate smaller pieces of memory instead of one big block.  Make abstraction of the fact that you need one big block (e.g. by writing a class around this big block).

If possible, I would go for the last alternative.

Comment: Or make it a true 64 bit process so that virtual memory never runs out :)

Comment: @Asha, yes of course.  That's the most obvious one that I always forget.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are on Windows. The amount of RAM available has nothing do with whether new can allocate memory or not. It is dependent whether 130 MB of contiguous virtual memory block is available in your process's virtual memory. Think of RAM as a limited scratch pad from where the OS can write and read very quickly. But if whatever it is looking for is not available in the scratch it will go to the disk and writes it to the scratch pad.

Comment: Thanks, Naveen. Is there any way to know whether whether 130 MB of contiguous virtual memory block is available in your process's virtual memory? I need some clues to tell me what happens on the earth. What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: You need to use Win32 APIs for that.. let me search for one.

Comment: @JoggingSong: You need to use `GetSystemInfo` along with `VirtualQuery`. See this delphi code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2356712/39742 and this C code http://blog.kalmbachnet.de/?postid=9